# Is there a reliable way to simulate a long running task in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, simulation, background-process

I'm trying to test long running  tasks in the for background task functionality on iOS.  I want to simulate a dummy task that runs X amount of seconds.  Is there a way to do that to test?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use `dispatch_after` and have the callback mark the task as complete.

```
let backgroundTaskIdentifier UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler { () -> Void in
    // TODO: Expiration handler
}
let numberOfSeconds = 10.0
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(numberOfSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // TODO: Verify task completion

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskIdentifier)
}
```